React Native OTP Input - Cursor Not Centered in TextInput Box
I’m building an OTP input component in React Native with four TextInput boxes, but I’m facing an issue where the cursor is not centered inside the box. Instead, it’s aligned to the right side of the box.
Here’s the relevant code I’m using:
<View style={styles.otpContainer}>
  {[...new Array(4)].map((_, index) => (
    <TextInput
      ref={ref => { inputs.current[index] = ref; }}
      style={[styles.otpInput, focusedIndex === index && { borderColor: tertiary }, emptyOtp && { borderColor: '#D00000' }, invalidOtp && { borderColor: '#D00000' }]}
      key={index}
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      maxLength={1}
      selectTextOnFocus
      contextMenuHidden
      testID={`OTPInput-${index}`}
      onChangeText={text => handleChangeText(text, index)}
      onKeyPress={e => handleKeyPress(e, index)}
      placeholder={focusedIndex !== index ? '•' : ''}
      onFocus={() => setFocusedIndex(index)} 
      onBlur={() => setFocusedIndex(-1)} 
    />
  ))}
</View>

otpContainer: {
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  gap: 8,
  marginTop: 40,
  textAlign: 'center',
},
otpInput: {
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#ccc',
  borderRadius: 8,
  paddingHorizontal: 16,
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontSize: 24,
  color: '#000',
  lineHeight: 55,
  width: 55,
  height: 55,
}

The TextInput cursor seems to be slightly off-center, leaning towards the right side. I’ve already ensured that the textAlign: 'center' is set, but it still doesn’t work as expected.
Things I’ve tried:

Removing padding and adjusting lineHeight.
Ensuring width and height are consistent with fontSize.
Adjusting textAlign properties.

Has anyone faced this issue before or have any suggestions for fixing the cursor alignment?

"slightly off-center, leaning towards the right side" - when you already applied texta-align: center, this most likely means the value of the input field isn't actually empty, but probably a space character ...?

when I remove textAlign: 'center', it aligns to the left instead of the center. How can I fix this and keep the cursor centered?

The paddingHorizontal property in your otpInput style may be causing the cursor to shift.
React Native TextInput cursor alignment can also be influenced by fontSize, lineHeight, and any additional padding or margins.
Try this:


otpInput: {
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderColor: '#ccc',
  borderRadius: 8,
  textAlign: 'center', // Horizontal alignment
  textAlignVertical: 'center', // Vertical alignment
  fontSize: 24, // Font size
  color: '#000', // Text color
  width: 55, // Box width
  height: 55, // Box height
  lineHeight: 55, // Match the height for vertical centering
  padding: 0, // Remove any padding
  margin: 0, // Avoid any margin conflicts
},




i tried ,it's not centrerd yet

You can try this code.


import { Text, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [focusedIndex, setFocusedIndex] = useState(-1);
  const inputs = useRef([]);

  const handleChangeText = (text, index) => {
    if (text && index < 3) {
      inputs.current[index + 1]?.focus();
    }
  };

  const handleKeyPress = (e, index) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace' && index > 0) {
      inputs.current[index - 1]?.focus();
    }
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.otpContainer}>
        {[...new Array(4)].map((_, index) => (
          <TextInput
            ref={(ref) => { inputs.current[index] = ref; }}
            style={[styles.otpInput, focusedIndex === index && { borderColor: 'blue' }]}
            key={index}
            keyboardType="number-pad"
            maxLength={1}
            selectTextOnFocus
            testID={`OTPInput-${index}`}
            onChangeText={(text) => handleChangeText(text, index)}
            onKeyPress={(e) => handleKeyPress(e, index)}
            placeholder={focusedIndex !== index ? '•' : ''}
            onFocus={() => setFocusedIndex(index)}
            onBlur={() => setFocusedIndex(-1)}
          />
        ))}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  otpContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginRight: 8,
  },
  otpInput: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#ccc',
    borderRadius: 8,
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 24,
    color: '#000',
    width: 56,
    height: 55,
  },
});



